# How to configure ssl in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I have followed [document](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/configure-ssl/#configure-mongod-and-mongos-for-ssl) to configure ssl in mongodb. But no luck.The mongod service doesnot start after configuring ssl in mongo.conf.
I have gone through and looks like i need to use Scon first to support SSL/TLS.
Can anyone please share steps or document, I need to follow first . 
I am using mongo version 2.6

Answer (score 0):

[This wiki](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source) should cover everything you need to build from source using scons.  Ensure you have the correct ssl package installed as mentioned in the [System Specific Requirements](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source#system-specific-requirements).  Your scons command will look

```
scons mongod --ssl
```

If you are able to upgrade to mongodb 3.0+ from 2.6 [most distributions include ssl support](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/configure-ssl/#mongodb-support).

Comment: Thanks @Irakai , but i have already installed mongodb , so is there any other way  apart from installing again and building with scons. Also if i try building with scons in an new installation, I get alot of build erroros for "scons all"

Comment: @GrinlikeaCheshirecat, I have added in the answer that upgrading to 3.0+ will likely include ssl support depending on your distribution.  That might be the shortest path by following the upgrade guide https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade